# How to check the prediction of my dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision, confusion-matrix

I am having 3 folders of datasets,

```
1- Face Images 
2- Non-Face Images 
3- Testing Dataset
```

I trained my dataset with SVM using FaceImages as `1` and Non-Face Images as `-1`. My file is trained and saved in `.xml` format. I checked the prediction on some of the images from Testing Dataset which is a mixture of the positive and negative datasets. Now I am trying to create a confusion matrix. I have read about it from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/confusion-matrix-machine-learning/).

In my testing dataset, images are almost 50, (35 Positive and 15 Negative) named as 1_F.jpg, 2_F.jpg, 3_NF ... 50NF.jpg. Here F is for Face and NF is Non-Face. These are actually names of images.

`Can I call it a labeled dataset?`

How I can create a confusion matrix as I apply it on all the images in a folder, How do I know If its correctly predicts the image?

From example [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/confusion-matrix-machine-learning/), they already have predicted matrix, but I think I don't have this one. I also checked [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60987/are-there-examples-of-labelled-and-unlabelled-data?newreg=149d117f91464adfb0f63482fcd18ef4) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170603/what-is-the-difference-between-labeled-and-unlabeled-data) for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the confusion matrix, checkout the `scikit-learn` library in Python. Assuming that `y_actual` is your set of test labels, the features corresponding to the images in your test set are stored in a variable called `X_test`, and your trained classifier as `clf`, one possible way to construct the confusion matrix is as below:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix 
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
## Obtaining confusion matrix below
CM = confusion_matrix(y_pred, y_actual)
```

*Can I call it a labeled dataset ?*

Without the original labels for your test set, you will not be able to confirm your predictions. From the confusion matrix, you can derive different metrics about your model's performance.

Given that you have named your images in the test set depending on the presence of a face or not, you could use this to obtain `y_actual`

```
import glob
import os

import numpy as np

def obtain_y_pred(test_folder):
    label = {'F':1, 'NF':-1}
    test_images = glob.glob(os.path.join(test_folder, '*.jpg'))
    y_test_ = []
    for image in test_images:
        y_test_.append(label[image.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0].split('_')[-1]])

    return np.array(y_test_)
```

To summarize, you first need to know the labels of your test set. Then you need to evaluate your model's performance on the *test set* after training it on the *training set*.

Comment: Thank you for such a nice explanation. last query, So I don't have to write 2_F, just F will work?

Comment: Each filename will have to unique of course. I think the idea of having the label encoded in the filename is a good idea, for the test set

Comment: And another suggestion. I just noticed that your file is saved in .xml format. Is that the classifier that you are saving as an .xml file?

Comment: Trained dataset is in .xml